# NSLocalizedString is not working for nsstring ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, ios9.3

I have

```
NSString *str=@"some unknown value coming from server";
NSString *localizedVersion1 = NSLocalizedString(str, nil);
NSLog(@"localizedVersion1 %@",localizedVersion1);
```

Getting:

> localizedVersion1  some unknown value coming from server .

It's not changing even when I am changing the device language.

Comment: Have you translated the string to other languages? Are those localized strings files being included in the app?

Comment: I have checked it's working  fine in google translator and also the value of str is unknown .Please help me to get out this situation.

Comment: What does this have to do with Google translator? You are talking about localizing an iOS app. You need to create localized copies of your strings file. Did you do that? Sounds like you need to read the [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i).

Comment: when I am  not aware of the string value which is coming from server then how would i add that value to localized copies.

Comment: anyone please help me.

Comment: Did you read the entire document I linked?

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the purpose of `NSLocalizedString`, it is not a *translation* service but a *lookup* one. With this mechanism an app can contain multiple sets of (UI) strings which are selected based on the current language setting. All the strings must exist in advance.

You mention using Google Translate on the web. If you need a translation service then you can use the [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/) in your app to provide this. There are other translation services available - just google for them.

HTH

Comment: Sorry last night I  figured out where was the able.Thanks for you advise.